# Is there a way to remove the %20 in Laravel URL?

Tags: laravel

Here's what I have so far.

in blade template

```
<a href='{{ url("/businessprofile/$business->id/$business->name") }}'>
```

and in web.php

```
Route::get('/businessprofile/{id}/{name}', 'BusinessController@show')
```

it shows

```
localhost:8000/businessprofile/User%20Info
```

is there a way to remove the %20 and just show localhost:8000/businessprofile/UserInfo instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Str::slug` method generates a URL friendly "slug" from the given string :

```
{{ url("/businessprofile/$business->id"."/" . Str::slug($business->name)) }}'>}}
```

Or,

```
{{ url("/businessprofile/$business->id"."/" . str_slug($business->name)) }}
```

If above method not work, then change your route & view as :

**route** :

```
Route::get('/businessprofile/{id}/{name}', 'BusinessController@show')->name('businessprofile.show');
```

**view** :

```
{{ route('businessprofile.show', ['id' => $business->id, 'name' => str_slug($business->name) ]) }}
```

See official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-str-slug)

Comment: thank you but it shows http://localhost:8000/businessprofile/1/str_slug(User%20Info)

Comment: @IvanvielleDupaya change your route and blade with my given data

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not do that. That's url encoding and ‰20 is code for space ( ).

Comment: my bad. already removed () and also tried mixing your idea with others and now I managed to replace " " with -. Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

change your url as below.

```
<a href="{{ url('businessprofile/'.$business->id.'/'.$business->name) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing your answers. I've tried mixing everyone's answer but the best I got is this

```
<a href='{{ url("/businessprofile/$business->id"."/".Str::slug($business->name)) }}'>
```

and it shows

http://localhost:8000/businessprofile/1/user-info